# Aside and Article overlapping the header

Tags: php, html, css, positioning

I'm remaking a website for Old Treasures Furniture and Imports in HTML5.

I have an issue with the positioning of the `aside` and `article` tags. They seem to like the header so much that they are on top of him.
I have tried to set the position of the two (`aside` and `article`) to `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`. I have tried `overflow: hidden;` on both as someone suggested in another thread i read. None have positioned them correctly as they should appear:

```
__________________________
|Header                  |
|------------------------|
|aside|article           |
|     |                  |
|_____|__________________|
|footer                  |
|------------------------|
```

Only footer is in his correct position.

**My `index.php`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Imports page's CSS style -->
<link href="01d7r345ur3557y13.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Sets Page FavIcon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/V6a6eGp.png" />
<title>Old Treasures Furniture and Imports</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Page Header/Banner Begin -->
<header alt="Old Treasures Furniture and Imports" />
<!-- Page Header/Banner End -->

<!-- Navigation Buttons Begin (Home, Products, Services, Contact) -->
<aside>
    <?php
        include("aside.php");
    ?>
</aside>
<!-- Navigation Buttons End -->

<!-- Content of Page Begin -->
<article>
    <img class="wagon" src="http://i.imgur.com/1hg8f8H.jpg" />
    <p>Welcome to Old Treasures Furniture and Imports, <br />We are a company dedicated to the manufacture and marketing of solid wood products.<br />Our services are oriented to decorators, builders, architects and clients like you.</p>
</article>
<!-- Content of Page End -->

<!-- Footer of Page Begin (Copyright, "Inline"-Share) -->
<footer>
    <?php
        include("footer.php");
    ?>
</footer>
<!-- Footer of Page End -->
</body>
</html>
```

**And my `01d7r345ur3557y13.css`:**

**(I omitted the rest of the CSS, i doubt they have an effect in this.)**

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/kRh8uzK.png?1") fixed;
}
header {
width: 65%;
height: 250px;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/jxzkFhn.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
margin: 20px auto;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
article {
border: 1px #fff solid;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/x1WvVZp.png");
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
}
footer p {
font-size: 10px;
}
header, footer, aside, article {
display: block;
}

/*Page Navigation*/
aside {
float: left;
width: 120px;
margin: 0;
}
aside li {
display: block;
}
aside ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.home {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ma42CHH.png");
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
width: 119px;
height: 31px;
}
.home:hover {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/iKLHtvh.png")
}
.products {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/sqBqNwp.png");
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
width: 119px;
height: 31px;
}
.products:hover {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/hRGXnqt.png?1");
}
.services {
background: url("");
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
width: 119px;
height: 31px;
}
.services:hover {
background: url("");
}
.contact {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/etMulj7.png");
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
width: 119px;
height: 31px;
}
.contact:hover {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/v4ZA6LH.png");
}
```

As of now, i'm still trying other methods to accomplish this issue. Many thanks!

This is the current website and how the positioning of the elements are supposed to be.
http://www.oldtreasuresfurniture.com/

And this is what I'm currently getting: [image: My Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) One issue I can see here is, you have used `header` tag as a self closing tag.

2) Make sure you have cleared the float at necessary places e.g. - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

3) It would be more helpful to debug, if you share URL of the page where you are facing the issue.

Comment: **SUPER FACEPALM**. I forgot i left the `header` tag open. That set things straight Thanks!